# React - Custom prop event

Tags: reactjs, events, react-props

I want to have a component with my own custom event prop - `onClickInside` but when I do I get an error:

> Warning: Unknown event handler property `onClickInside`. It will be ignored.

Is there any way to get around this or do I have to rename my event?

Example:

```
<ClickInside onClickInside={ () => doSomething() }>
```

Comment: show us the `<ClickInside />` component

Comment: It's not about the name, your event handler must be ending up on an HTML element, where React doesn't know what to do with it.